DbGeometry check for duplicates before insert in db takes too long
I have a problem inserting thousands of data into the database.
I need to check if a point with the exact same coordinates has already been inserted, but this operation takes too long, and over time it can only get worse because the points to check will increase.
Here is a part of code:
            // Initializing list of new points
            List<Point> newPointsList = new List<Point>();
            // Get list of point on this layer
            IQueryable<DbGeometry> oldGeometries = db.Points.Where(p => p.LayerId.Equals(layerId)).Select(p => p.Geometry);

            // Loop on features to insert into db
            for (int i = 0; i < newPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                // Create geometry for check
                DbGeometry newGeometry = DbGeometry.FromText(newPoints[i].positionWKT);

                // Check if a point exist in same position
                if (oldGeometries.Any((p) => p.SpatialEquals(newGeometry)))
                    // Skip in case of duplicate point
                    continue;

                // Add to list
                newPointsList.Add(newPoints[i]);
            }

            // Insert all points to db
            db.Points.AddRange(newPointsList);

            // Saving
            db.SaveChanges();

if I delete this part of code, the import takes place in a few minutes
                // Check if a point exist in same position
                if (oldGeometries.Any((p) => p.SpatialEquals(newGeometry)))
                    // Skip in case of duplicate point
                    continue;

otherwise it takes hours.
I tried changing the current check with a HashSet
HashSet<DbGeometry> hashpoints = new HashSet<DbGeometry>(oldGeometries);

// for loop

if (hashpoints.Contains(oldGeometries))


But it doesn't recognize duplicate points and imports everything.
How can I solve it?
Thank you

This code is the absolute slowest way to perform this. WKT means text, which means the field isn't covered by a spatial index. The query has to scan the entire table for every single item. Executing one client-side query per item is very slow too, just like executing N Where ID=@id queries instead of a single Where ID in (1,5,8,14,...)

EF is an ORM anyway, not an ingestion tool. It would be a lot faster to insert the data into a staging table that uses proper spatial columns and indexes, perform a JOIN with the target table and insert only the new items

Sorry, I forgot to say that newPoints is a json where I do a loop, for this reason I have to take the values one by one and they are in the form of a string, but in the end I do the comparison between DbGeometry, but if there are better methods they would be useful.
As for replacing entity framework, that's beyond the maintenance I'm currently performing and I can't do that currently.

I didn't say you should replace EF. I said you should map to a reporting view. You should also not work with a JSON field but an actual geography or geometry value if you intend to search for matches. Otherwise delays will always increase because your application will keep retrieving all rows to check them

WKT is a very specific, non-JSON standard. If you actually had a WKT string you could create a computed column with geography::STGeomFromText(positionWKT) and index it. After that you can use .STEquals(..) to compare two geography or geometry values for equality

Are you using GeoJSON? In that case check Loading GeoJSON data into SQL Server. The formatting is a bit ugly but essentially, the query is using OPENJSON to extract the data as columns and then using STGeomFromText to create a POINT. You can use that in a calculated expression and then equality checks
